How to smoothly use uView2 in the Uniapp environment?
General problem: When using uView in the Uniapp environment and publishing it to a mini program, due to strict specifications, my code looks very unappealing. Can you show me a better way to write it?
Description: When using uView in the Uniapp environment and publishing it to a mini program, it is necessary to strictly follow the API provided by the uView2 official website to write code. If a class="title" is added, it will become invalid and will be automatically deleted during compilation.
Preliminary solution: I chose to add: v-deep app container {} to the outermost layer of CSS, and then use the uView2 tag name for the class name, similar to writing CSS code in the form of:. u-form {}. This allows me to write CSS freely without being restricted by the API provided.
Problem: This writing method will fail when there are custom encapsulated sub components, such as custom tabbars. Explanation: If a part of the code is written in another file and imported into the main file through components, it will cause the method I used above to fail.
Summary: At the very least, it can solve the requirement of writing CSS arbitrarily when customizing child components. At present, no suitable method has been found

第一次发，翻译的有点乱，原始的编写文案：
总问题：当在uniapp环境下使用uView并将其发布到小程序时，由于规范严格，导致我的代码很不好看，有大佬给看看有更好的写法么？
描述：当在uniapp环境下使用uView并将其发布到小程序时，就需要严格按照 uView2官网提供的api进行编写代码，如果新增class="title" 这种，就会失效，编译时会被自动删掉。
初步解决方式：我选择了 css 的最外层加个 ::v-deep app-container {}，然后类名使用uView2的标签名，类似于：.u-form{} 形式编写css代码，这样可以做到随意写css，而不受api提供的限制。
问题：这种写法当有 自定义封装的子组件，类似于：自定义tabbar时，就会失效，解释：如果把 一部分代码 写道另一个文件内，通过components进行引入到 主文件，会导致我上面用的那种方式失效。
总结：可以解决 自定义子组件 时，任意编写css的需求。目前来 没找到合适的方法
